# What OpenLDAP ACL is necessary for Webmin?

Tags: openldap, webmin

I struggle in the arcane science of OpenLDAP ACL configuration.
I would like to store user login data in OpenLDAP and provide it to multiple services, so the users can use the same username and password for all the services.

I set up Virtualmin/Webmin on a VPS and I set up OpenLDAP and Webmin using the following instructions: https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/installation/ldap/
This way account data of Unix-users and Webmin-users is retrieved from LDAP.

Now I'd like to restrict the LDAP ACL as much as possible, but can't figure out how to do it. I thought of the following policy:

- Every LDAP-user of a service should have the least necessary read/write permissions to get the service working.
- Anonymous LDAP-users should be able to log in, but should not be able to read anything.
- LDAP-users corresponding to humans should not be able to read/write anything other than their own attributes (until it becomes necessary).

Using [these instructions](https://medium.com/@moep/keeping-your-sanity-while-designing-openldap-acls-9132068ed55c) I came up with the following ACL for OpenLDAP:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * break
olcAccess: {1}to * attrs=userPassword by self =xw by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by users read
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree=ou=WebminUG,dc=example,dc=com by dn="uid=WebminUG,ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com" write by users read
olcAccess: {4}to * by users read
```

Assuming, that the base DN is `dc=example,dc=com`.

Sadly, for whatever reason, this ACL does not work. Trying to log in to Webmin says "Login failed. Please try again." which is the same message, if the username or password do not match. Even `su Username` does not work in the shell (if `Username` is some Unix-user stored in LDAP), where the error says that the user does not exist.

Currently, I set the ACL to `olcAccess: to * by users write by anonymous read`, because I do not know how to be more strict without breaking the setup.

Could you help me figure out what to do? Why does my config deny access? I'll gladly give more detailed information if necessary.

**Edit:**
I think it fails, because I forgot to add a "catch-all" rule. The following works:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=mueli-deisswil,dc=ch" write by * break
olcAccess: {1}to * attrs=userPassword by self =xw by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by users read
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree=ou=WebminUG,dc=example,dc=com by dn="uid=WebminUG,ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com" write by users read
olcAccess: {4}to * by users write by anonymous read
```

But if I change the last line to `to * by users read by anonymous auth`, or only just change one of the two permissions to `read`/`auth`, then it fails again.

Is there a solution without `to * by anonymous read`?

For easier understanding how the layout of the directory looks like this:

```
dc=example,dc=com                       // Base DN

ou=people,dc=example,dc=com             // Here "human users" are stored
uid=Elie,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com    // Entry of Elie Xample. ;)

ou=unix-groups,dc=example,dc=com        // Here unix groups corresponding to unix accounts are stored
cn=Elie,ou=unix-groups,dc=example,dc=com

ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com           // Here the users of services are stored
uid=WebminUG,ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com
uid=NextCloud,ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com

ou=WebminUG,dc=example,dc=com           // Here the data of Webmin-Users is stored
cn=Elie,ou=WebminUG,dc=example,dc=com   // The Webmin-User of Elie Xample
```